# How do I configure Gnome 3 so that it doesn't pop up a dialog for 'open with files' when I mount a drive?

Tags: ubuntu

I am running Gnome 3 on Ubuntu 11.10.

In the file manager, when I click a drive under 'Devices', Gnome 3 always pops up a dialog with the choices 'open with files' and 'eject' and then I need to click 'open with files' to get rid of that dialog.

Is there a way to configure Gnome 3 not to do that? I am in file manager already, clicking a drive should show the content in the right pane. Why does it still ask me to 'open with files'?

Answer (score 2):

You have to disable prompt/start programs when media is inserted. Go to:

```
Activities > Applications > System Settings > Details > Removable Media
```

and check:

```
Never prompt or start programs on media insertion
```